# Display values ended in specific numbers pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
index  assets
1     12345
2     54343
3     39483000
4     2543553
5     22425000
6     5342334345
7     244224000
```

I want to display values ended on "000".

Df

```
index  assets
3      39483000
5      22425000
7     244224000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) after converting `assets` into `str` using [`pd.Series.astype(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
df[df.assets.astype(str).str.endswith('000')]

   index     assets
2      3   39483000
4      5   22425000
6      7  244224000
```

Or

[`pd.Series.mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) with [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df[df.assets.mod(1000).eq(0)]

   index     assets
2      3   39483000
4      5   22425000
6      7  244224000
```